# Write a Kernel-Modul for Linux VM

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel

This is my first time writing a question here so I apologize in advance if information is missing or I write in the wrong format. I'm currently taking a Systems class where we're working with Ubuntu VM to learn 'basic' Linux instructions and commands/programming. Our current project is to write our own Kernel-Modul and install it in Linux. Unfortunately it's in German but will post the entire thing and translate it best I can.

**Bauen Sie ihr eigenes Kernel-Modul mod_kmalloc.ko. Hierzu müssen Sie ein eigenes C-File anbieten und den Makefile anpassen.
Ihr Modul soll den Parameter „loop_cnt“ nehmen, der angibt wie häufig Speicher der Größe „alloc_size“ (ein weiterer Parameter) allokiert werden soll. Diese Speicherallokation messen Sie mittels
des Time-stamp-Counters mittels der Instruktion „rdtsc“ (auf Intel x86 / AMD64) bzw. mit hrtimers
(ARM) und geben das auf der Kernel-Console mittels printk() aus**

We're supposed to build out own Kernel-Modul and call it mod_kmalloc.ko. We're then using the loop_cnt parameter, which tells us how often the memory is allocated with alloc_size, with another parameter, and how often it should be done. And to measure the amount we need to use the rdtsc command, with everything then being given out onto the console through a printk() command/function.

From what I've learned so far and understand, I've made a 'proper' Makefile.

```
obj-m = mod_kmalloc.o

KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)

modules all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

What confuses me is how/what the C-File is supposed to have, and then how to install the new Modul/Kernal and make it run.
I sadly don't have much understand of Linux still, and at a total loss of what the first step should be. I know I need to use something along the line of

```
uint64_t rdtsc(){
    return __rdtsc();
}
```

but more than that and I'm at a total loss.

Comment: Would this help? [Hello world kernel module.](https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x121.html)

Comment: another one for inspiration ;) https://github.com/ngtkt0909/linux-kernel-module-template

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you an answer for your exercise, but I can provide you with the information needed to solve it:

### Parameter

Your kernel module need to define 2 parameters(`loop_cnt`, `alloc_size`), this can be done using the [`module_param()` macro](https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x323.html).

### Structure

Your module need to declare an init and exit method, have a look at the following [Hello World example](https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x281.htm) to get a basic understanding of the structure of a kernal module.

### Allocate Memory using kmalloc

The exercise states that you should allocate `loop_cnt` times the memory of size `alloc_size`. In order to do so use the [`kmalloc(alloc_size, GFP_KERNEL)`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kmalloc.html) method in a loop and allocate the size passed via parameters.
In Addition you should free the allocated space in the exit method of your module(see [`kfree`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kfree.html)).

### Measure clock cycles

Using [`rdtsc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/rdtsc?view=msvc-170) method will return the clock cycles count since the last reset of the processor. If you call [`rdtsc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/rdtsc?view=msvc-170) before and after each call to [`kmalloc`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kmalloc.html) and save the value returned in two variables you can subtract the two valuse and for example print it using [`printk`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-basics.html).

### Using the kernal module

Make sure your Makefile and C-File are in the same directory.
To build your module just run the command `make` in this directory.
To insert the module into the kernal you need to run the [`insmod`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/insmod) command.
In Addition you need to pass the module parameters to this command e.g. `sudo insmod mod_kmalloc.ko loop_cnt=3 alloc_size=3`.
Now you can check if the module was added: `lsmod | grep mod_kmallloc`.
And you can check the output using the following command: `dmesg | tail`.
To remove the module you can call `sudo rmmod mod_kmalloc`.